# How to use contravariant parameters in base class?

Tags: c#, inheritance, asp.net-web-api, contravariant

In a ASP.NET Web API 2.0-project I want to access with the HTTP verbs `GET` and `POST` similar objects from the data model, all implementing the interface `ITableRow`. So I have a base class offering default implementations of access to these model classes:

```
class ControllerBase 
{
  protected string whereAmI = "base controller";

  public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(whereAmI + ": GET");
    [... here is the default action to get the data object(s) ...]
  }

  public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] ITableRecord value) 
  {
    Console.WriteLine(whereAmI + ": POST " + value.GetType().ToString());
    [... here is the default action to create a new data object ...]
  }
}
```

and a derived class that wants to use the `ControllerBase` default implementation of `Post()`:

```
public class ElementsController : ControllerBase
{
  protected string whereAmI = "element controller";
}
```

Using the GET route works easy, but there is a problem calling the POST route:

The automatic call through the Web API 2.0 framework of the Post now calls the `ElementsController.Post()` method, but can't create an element object since it only knows it has to build an `ITableRecord` object as value - and since this is only an interface, the variable `value` stays `null`.

Now I can write in each of my derived classes a specific definition of `Post()`, calling the `ControllerBase.Post()` from there:

```
  public override IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] Element value) // this won't work since the argument types doesn't fit
  {
    return base.PostHelper(value); // so I have to call a helper function in base
  }
```

My question is: Is there a better (say: more DRY) way to tell the derived class which specific type the argument of the `Post()` method has to be, without ?

Comment: It looks like you should be using generics. For example:  `class ControllerBase<T> where T : ITableRecord`

Comment: @DavidG When I finally dared to take this path it was surprisingly simple! Won't you give this as answer?

Comment: As a bonus, you could also replace the `whereAmI` variable with `protected string WhereAmI => GetType().Name;` so you don't need to override it in your derived classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a job for generics. First, make your base class generic, and change the `Post` method to use the generic type. For example:

```
// Note the type constraint too, you may not want this depending on your use case
class ControllerBase<T> where T : ITableRecord
{
    public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] T value) 
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

And now your derived controller would look like this:

```
public class ElementsController : ControllerBase<Element>
{
    //...
}
```